# Placeholder en un select

Tags: php, html, css, html5

Estoy usando `placeholder` en mis `input` de tipo texto y funcionan perfecto, solo que tengo un `select`, en el cual le quiero poner un `placeholder` donde diga "selecciona una opción", pero no aparece, alguien sabe si puedo agregarlo? y como se puede agregar? Gracias, saludos

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Se puede agregar una primer opción deshabilitada, y al mismo tiempo seleccionada que sirva para mostrar un texto informativo:

```html
 <select>
    <option disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
    <option value="item 1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item 2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="item 3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hola @daniel, lo primero, bienvenido al sitio :). Sería bueno que agregaras una explicación de lo que hace tu código para que pueda servir mejor al autor o a futuros lectores que lleguen hasta aquí para encontrar una solución a su problema.

Answer (score 14):

Mejor

```html
<select>
    <option hidden selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
    <option value="item 1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item 2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="item 3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 6):

En un `select` no se puede agregar un `placeholder`, pero lo que puedes hacer es agregar un `option` con `value` vacío indicando lo que quieres agregar en el `placeholder`, así:

```html
<select>
        <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
        <option value="item 1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="item 2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="item 3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio de mucho tu respuesta, te lo agradezco:D

Comment: Genial, si te funcionó te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada para que los desarrolladores que tengan esa inquietud sepan cual es la solución correcta, te invito a que leas [Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para que te documentes mejor sobre el funcionamiento de las respuestas, saludos !